# Camel CQL Component - Query with multiple parameters

Tags: cassandra, apache-camel, cassandra-3.0, spring-camel

I'm creating an Camel route that consumes data from Cassandra DB using CQL component and I want to pass multiple parameters to the where statement.

How can I pass multiple parameters to construct the prepared stratement internally?

I've checked in DOC and I found the way to pass one parameter:

```java
rest("cassandra")
        .get()
            .route()
            .routeId("teste")
            .removeHeaders("Camel*")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple(HttpMethod.GET.name()))
            .process(e-> e.getIn().setBody("Gabriel")
            .to("cql://localhost:9042/teste?cql=SELECT * FROM teste_table where name = ? ALLOW FILTERING")
```

The way above works fine, but I want to pass more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some retries, I found a way to do it, simply passing an object array in the exchange in body, see below:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
...
rest("cassandra")
        .get()
            .route()
            .routeId("test-route")
            .removeHeaders("Camel*")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple(HttpMethod.GET.name()))
            .process(e-> e.getIn().setBody(new Object[] {"Gabriel", LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(1994, 10, 25)}))
            .to("cql://localhost:9042/teste?cql=SELECT * FROM teste_table where name = ? and date_of_birth= ? ALLOW FILTERING")
            .process(e -> {
                Row[] rows = e.getIn().getBody(Row[].class);
                for (Row row : rows)
                     System.out.println("name: " + row.getString("name") + ", idade: " + row.getInt("idade"));
            });
```